# /etc/bluetooth/main.conf doesn't include 'ControllerMode = le'

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, bluetooth

As a follow up to my last question, I followed the instructions as shown below:
https://github.com/ukBaz/python-bluezero/blob/master/docs/install_bluez.rst

and I looked in the directory /etc/Bluetooth and looked at the main.conf file but it didn't contain the line of code 'ControllerMode = le'.

What should I possibly do?

Answer (score 2):

You should add the line `ControllerMode = le`. Just type it in, save the file, then reboot.

Comment: Worked for me :)